# ST3 does not show right characters on win 8.1

Tags: sublimetext3

As on the title my OS is Win 8.1 k.

This windows version is for Korean users. Any way I`m using Sublime Text 3 latest version.

When I set the Korean file name wich is foreign language.
Characters are broken on the enhanced sidebar plugin and files names on the tab.
But on the editor part is perfectly working.

See this image. Please help me.

[image: this is evidence]

Comment: this question would probably give you better results on the ST3 forum

Comment: @samrap  
I already mentioned on the twitter and ask this problem on the userecho community but they did not any reply.....

Comment: @the1900 he means the [Sublime Text Forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum).

Comment: I just notify to github at [here](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/6520) thanks guys

Comment: See http://kipid.tistory.com/entry/Introducing-Sublime-Text-editor#secId1-6-2 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252045/sublime-text-sidebar-tab-go-to-anything-korean-chinese-japanese-broken

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `"dpi_scale": 1.0` in the user preference file and restart ST3.

See http://kipid.tistory.com/entry/Introducing-Sublime-Text-editor#secId1-6-2 and [Sublime text - (Sidebar/Tab/Go to anything) Korean/Chinese/Japanese broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252045/sublime-text-sidebar-tab-go-to-anything-korean-chinese-japanese-broken) for the details.