# Sublime text - (Sidebar/Tab/Go to anything) Korean/Chinese/Japanese broken

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am using sublime text 3 in Windows 10.

[image: go to anything broken]

[image: sidebar broken]

As you can see it from the above captures, Korean/Chinese/Japanese characters are broken in 'Go to Anything' text input, sidebar, and tab title.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I think that similar languages like Japanese, Chinese characters have the same problem.

Font setting in Preferences - Settings - Users does not solve this problem.

ps. This is not a problem of encoding of the text 'file'. It may come from the unappropriate Windows font that the `Sublime text.exe` is using. But I cannot find a way to change this. Changing Windows default font does not solve this problem. (I can definitely see Korean in Windows file explorer.)

Editted : See also [kipid's blog - Introducing Sublime Text editor - #Sidebar, Go to Anything, Tab label 에서의 한글깨짐 (Package - PackageResourceViewer)](http://kipid.tistory.com/entry/Introducing-Sublime-Text-editor#secId1-6-2) for the solution.

Comment: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/font.html

Comment: @pvg That setting does not solve this problem. The font setting applies only to the inside of text edit of files, not to the sidebar, tab title.

Comment: You can change those too, certainly the sidebar ones and I am reasonably sure the others. Takes a bit more digging and poking around the default theme. See http://superuser.com/questions/748381/sublime-text-3-sidebar-font-face-change

Comment: @pvg I answered the question you linked to, and `font.face` is probably the best bet here. The default font is likely `Arial`, which doesn't (to my knowledge) have extended Unicode support. The OP should be able to change the sidebar and the tabs, but I'm not sure about `Go To Anything`. I don't have time to work on this now, but if you're willing there's a good answer in it...

Comment: @MattDMo Thanks~! I resolved font in sidebar_label and tab_label, (but not in `Go To Anything`.) I am trying to find out the `GTA` font option in a `theme` file.

Comment: @pvg Thanks~! I resolved font in sidebar_label and tab_label, (but not in `Go To Anything`.) I am trying to find out the `GTA` font option in a `theme` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem: The ST3 installed in my Windows 7 machine could not display file names with Chinese characters correctly in the side bar and in the tab. I found this [solution in the Chinese website Zhihu](https://www.zhihu.com/question/24029280): Simply add `"dpi_scale": 1.0` in the user preference file and restart ST3. It works for me!

Answer (score 0):

1. in Sublime Text, press "Ctrl + `" to open Console, then type below code to install package control.

> import urllib.request,os; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp
>   = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) );
>   open(os.path.join(ipp, pf), 'wb').write(urllib.request.urlopen(
>   'http://sublime.wbond.net/' + pf.replace(' ','%20')).read())

2. restart Sublime Text
3. in Sublime Text, press "Ctrl + Shift + P" to open command mode, keyin "Install Package", select "Package Control: Install Package" from the drop down options
4. Now, key in "ConvertToUTF8" or "GBK Encoding Support".

done